# Multilevel index won't go away

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe, which consists of summary statistics of another dataframe:

```
df = sample[['Place','Lifeexp']]
df = df.groupby('Place').agg(['count','mean', 'max','min']).reset_index()
df = df.sort_values([('Lifeexp', 'count')], ascending=False)
```

When looking at the structure, the dataframe has a multi index, which makes plot creations difficult:

```
df.columns

MultiIndex(levels=[['Lifeexp', 'Place'], ['count', 'mean', 'max', 'min', '']],
           labels=[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [4, 0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

I tried the solutions of different questions here (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624039/pandas-reset-index-on-series-to-remove-multiindex?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)), but somehow don't get the desired result. I want df to have `Place`, `count`, `mean`,`max`, `min` as column names and delete `Lifeexp` so that I can create easy plots e.g. `df.plot.bar(x = "Place", y = 'count')`

Comment: Well your column multiindex is `['Lifeexp', 'Place']` which looks suspiciously like it came from `df = sample[['Place','Lifeexp']]`. Check if that's the case. Show us df.columns after each of the three lines of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think solution should be simplify define column after `groupby` for prevent `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df = df.groupby('Place')['Lifeexp'].agg(['count','mean', 'max','min']).reset_index()

df = df.sort_values('count', ascending=False)
```

Comment: I think @smci was correct. But this code works. Thank you both!