# How to make a pandas DataFrame into a dynamic table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I generate the following DataFrame by my optimization Results, using multiindex:

```
    hour         0       1        2
Scenario plant          
0        A       0,0831  0,08124  0,08124
         B       0,5     0,5      0,5
         C       0,4599  0,31246  0,16786
         D       0       0        0
```

But since I might want to transform it in Excel in a Pivot-Table, it would be better to have the index "Scenario" in every row like:

```
    hour         0       1        2
Scenario plant          
0        A       0,0831  0,08124  0,08124
0        B       0,5     0,5      0,5
0        C       0,4599  0,31246  0,16786
0        D       0       0        0
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: You can just use `.rest_index()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas reset index on series to remove multiindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624039/pandas-reset-index-on-series-to-remove-multiindex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked as stated in the comments with `.reset_index()`